# How to include bootstrap in a web page?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am able to use some of the bootstrap elements but not all. 
I have tried this, but I get an error for some of the elements attributes saying not a valid attribute for that element.

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
</head>
```

Comment: Which elements give you an issue? When you look at the browser's network tab in the developer tools, do the CSS and JS files get pulled down correctly?

Comment: I think,You just included the bootstrap theme. If you want bootstrap CSS, just included the following snippet to head tag. `<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: Your post is incomplete you need to describe more about what exactly you are looking for wrt. to current post every answer would be on fly. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @mason In the div tag the attributes data-target, data-ride, data-slide-to, gives an error - not a valid attribute of element div . Same goes for <a> tag the attribute role gives me same error.  I have tried including the links in same way as given on the bootstrap site but still some element attributes don't work. Is it because I need to use html5?

Comment: Early versions of VS aren't aware you can add attributes at random, but will still let you add them. The Intellisense is just wrong. Anyways, upgrade to VS 2015. And follow Sankar's instructions.

Comment: @mason I am a beginner and I need to develop my final year project. I am right now only comfortable with Visual Studio 2010. So VS 2010 doesn't support bootstrapping?

Comment: @Suprabhat Let me know how to include Bootstrapping in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: As I just explained, earlier versions of VS Intellisense will give warnings if you use those attributes. But you can ignore those warnings. The IDE you choose does not affect whether you can use Bootstrap or not.  But getting a newer IDE (VS 2015 Community is free for students!) will give you a nicer experience working with those newer libraries. Sankar's explained above why your code doesn't work in the browser.

Comment: @mason Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Sankar I included the bootstrap.min.css but still it is not working.

Comment: @ashwini can you show us what you have Done?

Comment: @Sankar I mean Carousel , drop down is not working.

Comment: @Ashwini: Can you post the HTML section where you have tried using carousel.

Comment: @Suprabhat [link](http://snag.gy/ETiRq.jpg)

Comment: OK, I have seen your link it's fine. If you are worried that the green underscore are the cause of carousel not working then forget that just like @mason said your current VS version doesn't recognize this attribute but when this page will opened in any cross browser it will work. Regarding the issue not working please have a look at browser developer console that the images you are trying to show have proper path or not.

Comment: @Suprabhat yeah Thanks and also thanks to mason First I thought because of the Intellisense my code was not working. But I can see the Carousel in the browser but the problem is when I click for the next image it doesn't work. Same goes for drop-down , I can see it in the browser but when I click on the drop down it doesn't respond.

Comment: @Ashwini: *Dropdown doesn't respond* you mean it doesn't open up in expanded form with list of options.

Comment: @Ashwini: You don't have Jquery library in first place. download and add that library in your js folder. and add the script link just above bootstrap.js. this will solve your issue. This will solve your Carousel issue too

Comment: @Suprabhat yes thanks. I checked the developer tools option in the browser . It said bootstrap requires higher version of jquery. carousel now works.

Comment: @Ashwini: Welcome, pleasure helping you out. Now both your carousel and dropdown are working na.

Comment: @Suprabhat Yes they are. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

in the head try this:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head >
```

and

before closing the body try this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

why the Jquery?
because without the Bootstrap does not work